# How to create pdf in r-markdown?

Tags: r

I'm new to Rstudio programming and I got problem with creating a PDF, R show error that 'can't find scatterplot function' and can't process with PDF creation.
I've been able to create test PDF, though.

The problematic chunk looks like this:

```
scatterplot(tablica$kurs, tablica$stopa_procentowa,
             smoother=NULL, 
             reg.line = lm,
             boxplots=FALSE, 
             main="Wykres rozrzutu dla zmiennych kursy i stopy procentowej")
```

I have installed packeges:

```
library("readxl")
library("magrittr")
library("dplyr")
library("plotly")
library("tinytex")
library("gridExtra")
library("reshape2")
library("kableExtra")
library("stargazer")
library("tseries")
library("stats")
library("knitr")
```

And also car.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually be about rmarkdown, just a matter of whether you remembered to load the packages you want to use. Loading a package and installing a package aren't the same thing

Comment: They are installed and loaded.

Comment: Is the package you need loaded within the markdown document, not just within your session? Knitting generally sets up a temporary environment separate from your session. Within the 2 chunks of code you posted, you haven't loaded `car`, assuming that's the package `scatterplot` comes from

Answer (score 0):

The `scatterplot()` function is from the `car` package. You must load the package using

```
library(car)
```

Comment: I have car installed and loaded.